# System.Timers.Timer gradually increasing interval?

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have been facing a very unique problem. I am using a System.Timers.Timer which triggers a method every minute. Gradually, I came to know the time interval is not constant.

For testing and ensuring the issue, i just run a timer which elapsed a function every minute. And the output was shocking, the timer interval seconds are not constant. They are changing thus so creating an issue.

```
12/13/2016 3:39:26 PM
12/13/2016 3:40:25 PM
12/13/2016 3:41:25 PM
12/13/2016 3:42:25 PM
12/13/2016 3:43:25 PM
12/13/2016 3:44:26 PM
12/13/2016 3:45:26 PM
12/13/2016 3:46:26 PM
12/13/2016 3:47:26 PM
12/13/2016 3:48:26 PM
12/13/2016 3:49:26 PM
12/13/2016 3:50:26 PM
12/13/2016 3:51:26 PM
```

As one can notice the interval is gradually increasing. The problem occurs when days expend. Thus so issue is creating like I have to process within the minute and the date is changed.

The code is simple

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 60000;
timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
timer.Start();
```

Comment: How is it gradually increasing? I see intervales between `59.?` and `60.?` with no apparent trend. Windows is not a real time OS, so the timer intervals will never be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve that issue. The solution is simple as

Set two checks at global level;

```
static bool _IsDirty = false, _TimerChecked = true;
```

Then handle the logic inside the `ElapsedEventHandler` as let DataSynchronizer is the delegate method then implementation could be as

```
private Task AdwordsPullDataSynchronizer(System.Timers.Timer timer)
{

     if (!_TimerChecked)
     {
          _IsDirty = false;
          timer.Stop();
          var interval = Convert.ToDouble(Math.Abs(DateTime.Now.Second - 60));
          timer.Interval = (interval + 2) * 1000;
          timer.Start();
          _TimerChecked = true;
     }

     if (DateTime.Now.Second > 10)
     {
         _IsDirty = true;
         _TimerChecked = false;
     }


     //Place your interval logic here

     if (_IsDirty)
     {
        timer.Stop();
        var interval = Convert.ToDouble(Math.Abs(DateTime.Now.Second - 60));
        timer.Interval = (interval + 2) * 1000;
        timer.Start();
     }

     return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

Pretty clear save side logic i have implemented.

What the code is doing is? It will check if the interval seconds greater than 10 then it will `reset the timer` and set the interval to next `ElapsedEvent 2nd second`. Then it will reset and `fixed the interval` to every `ElapsedEvent 2nd second`.

Answer (score 1):

System.Timers.Timer is not that precise.  Check the remarks section [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yup that's the issue, for me now more concern is how to handle this issue

Comment: I haven't implemented this myself, but you may want to use the media high-precision timers.  Here you can find a wrapper implementation in C#: http://web.archive.org/web/20110910100053/http://www.indigo79.net/archives/27